# Generating a matrix containing 3 numbers

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am trying to create an 8x8 matrix containing 0s, 1s and 2s. Each row and each column should contain two 0s, three 1s and three 2s.

Previously I have used the below to generate an example containing only 1s and 0s.

```
output = zeros(8, 8);
for i=1:8
    tmp = (1:8) + (i); 
    tmp = rem(tmp, 4);
    output(i,:) = tmp;
    output(i,:) = tmp > 0;
end

output =

 1     1     0     1     1     1     0     1
 1     0     1     1     1     0     1     1
 0     1     1     1     0     1     1     1
 1     1     1     0     1     1     1     0
 1     1     0     1     1     1     0     1
 1     0     1     1     1     0     1     1
 0     1     1     1     0     1     1     1
 1     1     1     0     1     1     1     0
```

However I would now like something similar to the following:

```
    output =

 1     1     0     1     2     2     0     2
 1     0     1     2     2     0     2     1
 0     1     2     2     0     2     1     1
 1     2     2     0     2     1     1     0
 2     2     0     2     1     1     0     1
 2     0     2     1     1     0     1     2
 0     2     1     1     0     1     2     2
 2     1     1     0     1     2     2     0
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have in your example is a [Hankel matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_matrix) so you could use the `hankel` function

```
c = [1  1  0  1  2  2  0  2];
k = [2  1  1  0  1  2  2  0];
A = hankel(c,k)
```

where `c` is the first column of the output matrix and `k` is the last row.

Making your output matrix a Hankel matrix is a good idea (based on your requirements) as it will enforce the row **and** column frequency counts for each value. You would not necessarily get this just by creating rows that are random permutations of a base row (using `randperm` for example) as duplicate rows would be possible which would break your column requirements.

As an example, if you want random `c` with fixed numbers of specific elements, you can randomly permute a base vector containing the required values and frequencies - as per your requirement this would be

```
c = [0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2];
index = randperm(numel(c));
c = c(index);

c =

   0   2   0   2   2   1   1   1
```

To get the square Hankel structure then choose `k` to be the next cyclic permutation of `c`

```
k = circshift(c',1)'

k =

    1   0   2   0   2   2   1   1
```

and just call `hankel` with these as mentioned above

```
A = hankel(c,k)

A =

   0   2   0   2   2   1   1   1
   2   0   2   2   1   1   1   0
   0   2   2   1   1   1   0   2
   2   2   1   1   1   0   2   0
   2   1   1   1   0   2   0   2
   1   1   1   0   2   0   2   2
   1   1   0   2   0   2   2   1
   1   0   2   0   2   2   1   1
```

The above output is based on what I got on my machine based on the output from `randperm`.

Any output matrix generated using the above will meet your requirements specified in the question.

Comment: Thanks. This does exactly what I wanted.